# Meteor data keeps stacking when displayed

Tags: image, meteor

I'm working on a school project where I can post images online using meteor.
I was able to post image and display the datas, but it's keep stacking to the other images. Is there any wasy to fix this? Here's the picture:

[image: My image]

And here's my code that displays the datas:

```
<template name="posts">
{{#if currentUser}}
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
    {{#each postList}}
    <div class="grid-item">
        {{updateMasonry}}
        <img src="{{this.url}}">
        {{#each postData}}
            {{this.username}}
            <br>
            {{this.message}}
            <br>
            {{this.createdAt}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: what's this line doing `<div class="grid-sizer"></div>` if there's nothing inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd want to bust it up into another template. You'd have your larger posts templates that would hold the images+comments and then you'd make a new template for each images.

So having a separate template for each of your image posts

```
<template name="images">
<div>
    <img src="{{url}}"/>
    {{#each postData}}
        {username}}
        <br/>
        {{message}}
        <br/>            
        {{createdAt}}
    {{/each}}
</div>
</template>
```

You can pass data into your template and you can only pull postData that is already meant for that image, instead of having everything jumbled into 1 template. 
It's probably best practice to split up your templates in the above fashion and properly pass data to each image post instead of grouping everything into 1 template.

https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-guide-to-meteor-templates-data-contexts/